# Algebraic Equation vs Algebraic Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

By definition, a function given by $y=f(x)$ is algebraic if it can be expressed in the
form
$$p_n(x)y^n+p_{n-1}(x)y^{n-1}+⋯+p_1(x)y+p_0(x)=0$$
where $p_0(x), p_1(x),...,p_n(x)$ are polynomials and $p_n(x)\ne0$. Polynomials are a special cese of algebraic functions
that are represented generally by
$$p_n(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+⋯+a_1x+a_0$$
But according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation an **algebraic equation** or **polynomial equation** is an equation of the form $$P=Q$$
where P and Q are polynomials with coefficients in some field. Why does in this definition "algebraic equation" is equivalent to "polynomial equation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call a number $x \in \mathbb{C}$ "algebraic" if it satisfies some polynomial relation $a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + ... + a_n = 0$. Immediately we see the similarities: a function is "algebraic" if it satisfies a polynomial relation like that above (replacing $x$ by $f(x)$). The latter terminology, "algebraic equation", is more historical: the original theory of 'algebra' is that of solving polynomial equations. But it's not hard to see how these definitions of "algebraic" came about - they're just solutions of polynomial equations in their respective areas (one with $x \in \mathbb{C}$, and the other with $f$ a function!)